# Kotlin: How to create/append file (and share)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, file-io

I have a list of arrays of data in my app that I would now like to write to a file (csv) and use a 3rd party app (such as email) to share this csv file. I have had no luck finding any helpful resources for creating, finding the file path for, and appending to a file in Kotlin. Does anyone have experience with this or have examples to point to? Just to get started I'm trying to write the header and close the file so I can see that it is correctly writing.

This is what I have for now:

```
val HEADER = "ID, time, PSI1, PSI2, PSI3, speed1, speed2, temp1, temp2"
val filename = "export.csv"

var fileOutStream : FileOutputStream = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

try {
    fileOutStream.write(HEADER.toByteArray())
    fileOutStream.close()
}catch(e: Exception){
    Log.i("TAG", e.toString())
}
```

It doesn't throw the exception, but I cannot find the file in the file system. I'm using a physical tablet for testing/debug. I've checked the com.... folder for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there are many ways to create a file and append to it, depending on the minimum API version you are developing for. I am using minimum Android API 22. The code to create/append a file is below:

```
val HEADER = "DATE,NAME,AMOUNT_DUE,AMOUNT_PAID"

var filename = "export.csv"

var path = getExternalFilesDir(null)   //get file directory for this package 
                                       //(Android/data/.../files | ... is your app package)

//create fileOut object
var fileOut = File(path, filename)

//delete any file object with path and filename that already exists
fileOut.delete()

//create a new file
fileOut.createNewFile()

//append the header and a newline
fileOut.appendText(HEADER)
fileOut.appendText("\n")


/*
    write other data to file 
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot find the file in the file system

Use Android Studio's Device File Explorer and look in `/data/data/.../files/`, where `...` is your application ID.

Also, you can write your code a bit more concisely as:

```
try {
    PrintWriter(openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).use {
        it.println(HEADER)
    }
} catch(e: Exception) {
    Log.e("TAG", e.toString())
}
```

`use()` will automatically close the `PrintWriter`, and `PrintWriter` gives you a more natural API for writing out text.

Answer (score 0):

`openFileOutput()` creates a private file, likely inside of app storage. These files are not browsable by default. If you want to create a file that can be browsed to, you'll need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and will want to create files into a directory such as is provided by `getExternalFilesDir()`

Comment: Can you show how to use getExternalFilesDir()? Andorid Dev says that it returns a File[] with the absolute path to where my app can create persistent files. Not really sure what File[] is, or how to use it with another function. Or, which function to use once I've called getExternalFilesDir().